# Assigning a thread to a variable to control it

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that i want to set the status of from the thread that started it. I have this code:

```
public static AnimationThread animThread;


public static void main(String args[]) {
    animThread = new AnimationThread();
}

public synchronized static void restart() {
    animThread.setDead();

}
```

I am getting a null pointer when i call the setDead method which is just setting a boolean flag that will cause the thread to finish.
On debugging I can clearly see that the animThread variable is never being assigned.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

---

```
public class Manager {

public static Graph graph = new Graph();
public static Gui gui;
public static AnimationThread animThread;
private static boolean forcedNew = false;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    gui = new Gui();
    gui.launch();
    animThread = new AnimationThread();
}

public synchronized static void restart() {
    forcedNew = true;
    if (EventQueue.getAnimationCounter() != 0) {
        EventQueue.insertEvent(EventQueue.getAnimationCounter()+1, new EndOfAlgo());
    }
    animThread.setDead();
    EventQueue.resetEventQueue();
    animThread = new AnimationThread();
    gui.killGUI();
    gui = new Gui();
    graph = new Graph();
    gui.launch();
    forcedNew = false;

}

public static boolean getForcedStatus() {
    return forcedNew;
}
}
```

This is the class that i want to control the thread from (above)

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at animation.main.Manager.restart(Manager.java:27)
at animation.gui.Gui$ListenMenuNew.actionPerformed(Gui.java:112)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Comment: With what is shown, this should clearly work, so there must be something else happening in the rest of your code.  Could you post more of your code, along with a stack trace showing the NullPointerException?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Please whittle your test down as small as you can to demonstrate the problem, then post the complete example.

Comment: Post a SSCCE(http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because you are reading the variable from a different thread then you are assigning it.  Without synchronization, Java does not have to make changes from one thread visible in another thread.

To solve this initialize it as it is declared as mentioned by Tudor.  This will only work if it does not require access to GUI.

Make the variable volatile, but you will have a race condition since the GUI may be visible before the variable gets set.

Only read and write to the animThread variable in a synchronized block.

Create and show the gui and initialize animThread all on the EDT.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     gui = new Gui();
     gui.launch();
     animThread = new AnimationThread();

   }
});
```

This prevents the action performed method from being called before the variable is initialized.  This will only work if you only access the animThread variable from the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the thread directly at the declaration:

```
public static AnimationThread animThread = new AnimationThread();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mot likely `gui.launch` does not return, as a result of which `animThread` will not be initialized in `main`. Then calling `restart` (as a result of pressing a button in the GUI by the looks of it) will lead to an NPE because `animThread` is still `null` the first time you get there.

Comment: `gui.lauch` does return and the variable is being set in the first instance. But looses its link at some point. There is no other refernce to the animThread variable in my code. In the thread class i have - could it be the problem? : `public AnimationThread() {
  t = new Thread(this, "Animation Thread");
  EventQueue.setAnimationCounter(0);
  alive = true;
  t.run();
 }`

Comment: Not sure, but calling `run` on a `Thread` instance will not spawn a new thread. It'll just call `run` of the `Runnable` on the current thread.